# Vs code Wrong Output

Tags: arrays, c, visual-studio-code, insertion-sort

Why I am getting **Wrong Output** in **Visual Studio Code** while Doing Insertion in Array Using this method? In other Online Compiler it's Working Fine But not in Vs Code. Is it a Glitch if Yes then How can I Fix it?

[Refer this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AMT6.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please avoid posting images (or worse, links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Please **Do Not** post your code as an image, post is as a text instead. [Here is why you should not post your code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15366635)